# rails render partial not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, ruby-on-rails-4, renderpartial

this is my simple code

```
<%= render :partial => '/manage/regions/get_by_country', :locals => {:country_id => @last_search.country_id} %>
```

the @last_search.country_id has value (checked)

but while rendering the control seems that the country_id is null or empty

what i cant understand is that i use same syntax in another control and work us expected

i try also  add hardcoded country_id

```
<%@id = 118%>
           <%= render :partial => 'manage/regions/get_by_country', :locals => {:country_id => @id} %>
          <%end%>
```

and not working
the control rendering but the country_id is null

Comment: Your code should work. but try this: `render 'manage/regions/get_by_country', :country_id => @last_search.country_id`

Comment: Post your **manage/regions/get_by_country** page code

Answer (score 0):

OK i got the problem

the variable on the partial named @country_id
and i passed country_id (with no the '@')

i actually don't know why in one controller its work and on the other it doesn't work

but when i change the variable on the partial to country_id (with no the '@')

its work as expected

thanks